# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Spring MVC Web App

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm developing a Spring MVC Web app, using Maven(Webapp archetype), Spring 5, Java 17 and Tomcat 9.0;

When I'm tryin' to deploy my artefact, I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletException and I can't understand why, given the fact that I'm using Tomcat 9.0 which makes use of javax packages.

But when I deploy on Tomcat 10.x, it is working perfectly fine.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-mvc-demo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-indexer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
      <scope>optional</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-r2dbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-r2dbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-demo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `jakarta.*` vs. `javax.*`

Comment: Idk why you downgraded my question? And youR comment doesn't explain much.

Comment: from the  [tomcat 10 migration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html) *The Java package has changed from javax.servlet to jakarta.servlet.* You import javax.servlet in your project. You have tochange the libraries

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 9 and I import javax.*, so it should work...

Comment: You are mixing Spring 6 with Spring 5 jars. That isn't going to work. Either use all the same Spring 5 versions and use Tomcat 9 (JavaE) **or** use all Spring 6 versions and use Tomcat10 (JakartaEE). Currently you are mixing, which is always a bad idea.

Comment: There must be one place where your project refer to jakartax. Can you please share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @M.Deinum That was the problem, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your dependencies you are mixing jars from different versions of a framework. In this case the framework is Spring and you are mixing jars from version 5.3.25 and 6.0.5. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework (regardless the framework) as that is trouble waiting to happen.

Fix the versions to all match.

**PRO-TIP:** Use the `dependencyManagement` section and import the Spring Framework BOM so you only need to define 1 version instead of for each module.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-mvc-demo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.25</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
      <scope>optional</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-demo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```